# Wordpress + subfolder + htaccess + internet explorer 7/9 = loop of redirect

Tags: php, internet-explorer, .htaccess, wordpress

I have a problem with a website designed with wordpress in a sub folder.

[Site www.risvegliati.it/blog/](http://www.risvegliati.it/blog/)

Because if I try to browse with Internet Explorer gives me error 404? It goes in a loop with the redirect:

[Site error http://www.risvegliati.it/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/....](http://www.risvegliati.it/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/)

this is the file index of [http://www.risvegliati.it/](http://www.risvegliati.it)

```
<?php 
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://www.risvegliati.it/blog" );
?>
```

end this is the htaccess file of /blog

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPressenter code here
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe try rewrite base of /  instead of /blog/.  I'm not sure though.

Comment: or remove the `/blog/` part from the last `RewriteRule`